# Como fazer duas verificações no select

Tags: php, sql

Eu tenho 3 selects em meu código onde:

- Caso o usuário informe a data inicial e a data final irá mostrar os dados entre elas.
- Caso o usuário informe a nota fiscal irá mostrar os dados com essa nota.
- Caso o usuário selecione o periférico irá mostrar todos os dados com esse nome cadastrado.

Agora minha dúvida é:
 Como fazer com que o select fique:

- Caso selecione **data inicial /data final e periférico**, seja mostrado os
  periféricos (com o nome informado) cadastrados dentro das datas
  definidas?
- Caso selecione **nota fiscal e periférico** só mostre o
  periférico selecionado daquela nota!

Código dos selects:

```
if($w_op == "P"){ //P é o periférico
    $w_query="where sai_tb_peri.seq_peri = '$w_cb_peri'";   
}
else
if($w_op == "N"){ //N é a nota fiscal
    $w_query="where sai_cad_nf.num_nf = '$w_tx_nota'";
}
else{ //Caso for nenhum é as datas
$w_query="where sai_cad_nf.dt_nota_fisc between '$w_tx_dt_inic' and '$w_tx_dt_fina'";
}

$w_querybusca="SELECT * FROM sai_cad_cara_peri
                    INNER JOIN sai_tb_peri on sai_cad_cara_peri.fk_seq_peri = sai_tb_peri.seq_peri
                    INNER JOIN sai_cad_nf ON sai_cad_cara_peri.fk_seq_nf = sai_cad_nf.seq_nf $w_query;";
```

Answer (score 1):

Eu não colocaria esses `else's` a principio, inicialmente, para ajudar já criaria a variavel $w_query com um valor 'where 1=1' (pog, mas ajuda muito) e ficaria algo assim, não testei e não sei se vai dar certo!!!

```
$w_query = "where 1=1"

if($w_op == "P"){ //P é o periférico
    $w_query .= " AND sai_tb_peri.seq_peri = '$w_cb_peri'";
}

if($w_op == "N"){ //N é a nota fiscal
    $w_query .= " AND sai_cad_nf.num_nf = '$w_tx_nota'";
}

$w_query .= " AND sai_cad_nf.dt_nota_fisc between '$w_tx_dt_inic' and '$w_tx_dt_fina'";


$w_querybusca="SELECT * FROM sai_cad_cara_peri
                    INNER JOIN sai_tb_peri on sai_cad_cara_peri.fk_seq_peri = sai_tb_peri.seq_peri
                    INNER JOIN sai_cad_nf ON sai_cad_cara_peri.fk_seq_nf = sai_cad_nf.seq_nf";
$w_querybusca.= $w_query;
```

Comment: É .. Obrigado @MarceloDiniz mas acabou não dando certo!

Comment: ok, mas o que não deu certo?

Comment: O próprio select não reconhece a clausula `$w_query`! Irei fazer umas alterações e já reedito aqui!

Comment: Fiz uma pequena alteração, ve se era isso, ou se puder dar mais detalhes dos erros! Quando tenta imprimir a $w_querybusca o que da?

Answer (score 0):

Reescrevendo seu código, o uso `switch` é mais aconselhável que o uso do `if..else`, em todas ocasiões que puder substituir seus `if` por `switch`, o faça.

```
switch ($w_op) 
{
case "P":
    $w_where = "where sai_tb_peri.seq_peri = '$w_cb_peri'";   
    break;
case "N":
    $w_where = "where sai_cad_nf.num_nf = '$w_tx_nota'";
    break;
default:
    $w_where = "where sai_cad_nf.dt_nota_fisc between '$w_tx_dt_inic' and '$w_tx_dt_fina'";
}

$w_query = "SELECT * FROM sai_cad_cara_peri ".
           "INNER JOIN sai_tb_peri on sai_cad_cara_peri.fk_seq_peri = sai_tb_peri.seq_peri ".
           "INNER JOIN sai_cad_nf ON sai_cad_cara_peri.fk_seq_nf = sai_cad_nf.seq_nf ";
$w_query .= $w_where;
```

Para ajuda-lo com a *query* em si, ou até mesmo a estrutura, acredito que sua pergunta poderia ser complementada com mais informações sobre o banco, a recepção das informações de entrada, saída, etc.

Uma sugestão: Não monte *query's* complexas no *PHP*, opite por montar uma `VIEW` que faça o a junção e na sua aplicação o código ficará mais limpo e mais fácil de trabalhar. Cada um com suas responsabilidades, banco também pode (e deve) ter uma estrutura mais trabalhada, `views`, `procedures`, `triggers`, `functions`.